# Error 404 : /j_spring_security_check is not available

Tags: jsf, spring-security

I tried to integrate Spring Security on JSF in a authentication form , the private page need now a authentication , but when I enter login and password  ,this error is diplayed

```
Error 404 : Project/j_spring_security_check is not available
```

So I created a JSF form :

```
    <h:form id="loginForm" prependId="false" >
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
<h:inputText class="form-control"  id="j_username" required="true"/>
 <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
 <h:inputSecret  class="form-control" id="j_password" required="true"/>
   <h:commandButton  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" action="#{authentication.doLogin()}" value="Login" />
 </h:form>
```

The function doLogin() in authentication bean is defined like that :

```
public String doLogin() throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        ExternalContext context=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher=((ServletRequest)context.getRequest()).getRequestDispatcher("j_spring_security_check");
        dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest)context.getRequest(),(ServletResponse)context.getResponse());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        return null;
    }
```

the Spring-security.xml :

```
<http auto-config="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/login.xhtml*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
<intercept-url pattern="/Backoff/*" access="ROLE_USER"/>
<form-login login-page="/login.xhtml" default-target-url="/Backoff/activities.xhtml"
always-use-default-target="true" 
authentication-failure-url="/Front/error.xhtml"  /> 
</http>
```

What I should add to make it works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem you can follow this steps below:

1-Change your Spring-security.xml like this:

```
 <http use-expressions="true">

<intercept-url pattern="/login.xhtml*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
<intercept-url pattern="/Backoff/*" access="ROLE_USER"/>
<form-login 
       login-page="/login.xhtml" 
       default-target-url="/Backoff/activities.xhtml"
       always-use-default-target="true" 
       authentication-failure-url="/Front/error.xhtml"
       <!--
        if you want to use primefaces components you can use this:
        password-parameter="j_idt10" : Name of password input
        username-parameter="j_idt8" : Name of username input 
        ==>To get the name of your inputs you can use "element inspection" offred by you browser (chrome,firefox)
          -->

     />  
</http>
```

2-Change your JSF form like this

```
<h:form id="loginForm" prependId="false" onsubmit="document.getElementById('loginForm').action='j_spring_security_check';" >
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
<h:inputText id="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-control"  name="j_username" required="true"/>
 <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
 <h:inputSecret  id="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-control" name="j_password" required="true"/>
   <h:commandButton  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Login" />
 </h:form>
```

You can notice that i remove the action of your commandButton and i change id of your inputs to name, i also add the `onsubmit` function inside form

Hope this help you out

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>`

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

[Custom login page with JSF and Spring-Security 3](http://slackspace.de/articles/custom-login-page-with-jsf-and-spring-security-3-2/)